# Python - How to make URL protocol call upon function

Tags: python, function, parsing, url, protocols

I'm making an application that would normally launch from a web browser. Because the original application was made in Python, I have made a script that launches the app. The script will then be turned into an exe. I have made it so that by clicking on the app, it does not launch the game, making it so that the user has to launch from the browser.

How would I make the URL protocol launch the function?

```py
   def launch(str):
       import os
       os.startfile("C:\Documents and Settings\app\my_app.exe")
       return;
```

Comment: you would need web server (you can use Python's web frameworks like Django, Flask, Bottle) and then web browser can access url on server which will run your function. But function will run .exe program on server, not on user's computer. Servers (and browsers) can't run programs on user's computer for security reason. But hackers still try to find bugs in browser to run programs on user's computer to steal paswords, naked images and money.